# b trees working in clustered Index

Tags: sql, database, indexing, b-tree, clustered-index

I'm trying to understand behind the scenes working of clustered index which gets developed in the form of binary tree on primary key column.

After reading couple of studies, All other nodes including the root node only hold the key values and pointers to the next nodes. Here the confusion starts. I'm not able to understand what would be the key values and pointers if I create clustered index on ID column in below table.

What picture is in my mind lets say I'm having a table with two columns, ID and NAME

```
    ID  NAME
    1   A
    2   B
    3   C
    4   D
    5   E
    6   F
    7   G
    8   H
    9   I
    10  J
    11  K
    12  L
    13  M
    14  N
    15  O
    16  P
    17  Q
    18  R
    19  S
    20  T
```

And I have created a primary key on column ID. So once I have created a primary key it generates clustered index on column ID using B-tree algorithm and store all values of this column in btree structure.

I want to understand from here, When a btree like structure starts building what values(what are pointers and indexes in above column ID) every branch node and leaf node holds, And On what basis it routes to the leaf level via branch nodes...?

And how it works if a clustered index gets create on string type column level..?

Thanks

Comment: A "b-tree" is not a *binary* tree.  It is a *balanced* tree.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, But I guess the whole concept is derived from b-tree only.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. How a B tree works is a good subject for a lecture or a chapter in a book, but too long for an answer here.